# Compatibility between compile time Hibernate version and Wildfly's provided on

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

My current project's target is Wildfly 10, which provides an implementation of JPA 2.1: it uses Hibernate **5.0.7.Final**

Is it safe to use an hibernate compile time dependency with a version **5.0.12.Final** ? Or should I stick with a version which is lower or equal to the one the application server is running ?

I don't understand well this subject, so any pointer to a good explanation is welcome.

Note: I know that the hibernate version on wildfly can be upgraded, but It should not be done in our environment.

Thanks

*--Edited--*

Further details about the pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Java EE 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <!-- compile dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The core hibernate libraries are probably provided by the container, but I have a dependency on *hibernate-jpamodelgen* for typesafe Criteria queries.

Is there a way to know what the javaee-api artifact encompasses?

Comment: why you would like to put hibernate dependency for your project? Just use JPA and let wildfly decide the persistence implementation ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Compile means you will pack the dependency together with your app/war. First of all, you can run into some classpath problems if you don't understand how the classloader works for each deploy you have in your wildfly. Apart from that, if each app packs their dependencies that are already in the classpath, you'll end up with a lot of unnecessary use of disk space and memory.

I recommend you to read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly?_sscc=t)

Comment: Thanks for this link. As you can see, I edited my original post, since my first assumption was not correct: as it seems, there is no compile dependency the hibernate core libraries. This explains why I cannot find the jar within my war archive.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively safe, the Hibernate team does not allow API changes in micro updates.

You would need to make sure your code is using the API only though; if you have custom extension which extract internal implementation details and/or extend internals you might hit some changes; the best way to be safe about this is to use the exact same version at development time.

The better alternative would be to upgrade the Hibernate versions you use; you can use a more recent version by including it in your application (although this would need to set some additional configuration properties - see the [WildFly JPA wiki](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide)) or upgrade the one in the application server.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added a snippet of the pom.xml file. I cannot find any other reference to hibernate. I have inspected the content of the produced war file (specially the *WEB-INF/lib* folder), and there is actually no hibernate jar file. Do you know whether it compiles because of the javaee-api dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

From the pom.xml you posted and the fact you are targeting Wildfly i would  set it to provided and set the version to the one Wildfly 10 provides. This way it's the safest option:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Also the two `javaee-api`'s are `redundant`. `javaee-web-api` is a subset of `javaee-api`. I would remove the `javaee-web-api`.

Comment: Hi Robert, you're right about the redundancy, I removed *javaee-web-api*, and I followed your advice.